# Azure Communication service - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, azure, azure-communication-services

I am working on a flutter project and trying to implement Azure Communication Services(video call) into my project. I tried to follow the example from the official website for Android Implementation.

I was also not able to run sample app available on [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-android-quickstarts/tree/main/videoCallingQuickstart), faced a [issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-android-quickstarts/issues/37).

Have anyone tried implementing azure communication video call with flutter?

Thanks in Advance.